# Adding x axis labels when using dojox.charting.DataSeries

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I'm creating a Dojo line chart from a dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore using a dojox.charting.DataSeries. I'm using the third parameter (value) of the constructor of DataSeries to specify a method which will generate the points on the chart. e.g.

```
function formatLineGraphItem(store,item) 
{   
    var o = {
        x: graphIndex++, 
        y: store.getValue(item, "fileSize"),
    };
    return o;
}
```

The graphIndex is an integer which is incremented for every fileSize value. This gives me a line chart with the fileSize shown against a numeric count. This works fine.

What I'd like is to be able to specify the x axis label to use instead of the value of graphIndex i.e. the under lying data will still be 1,2,3,4 but the label will show text (in this case the time at which the file size was captured).

I can do this by passing in an array of labels into the x asis when I call chart.addAxis() but this requires me to know the the values before I iterate through the data. e.g.

```
var dataSeriesConfig = {query: {id: "*"}};
var xAxisLabels = [{text:"2011-11-20",value:1},{text:"2011-11-21",value:2},{text:"2011-11-22",value:3}];

var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart("chart1");
chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines", tension: "4"});
chart1.addAxis("x", {labels: xAxisLabels});
chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
chart1.addSeries("Values", new dojox.charting.DataSeries(dataStore, dataSeriesConfig, formatLineGraphItem));
chart1.render();
```

The xAxisLabels array can be created by preparsing the dataSeries but it's not a very nice work around.

Does anyone have any ideas how the formatLineGraphItem method could be extended to provide the x axis labels. Or does anyone have any documentation on what values the object o can contain?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This will take a unix timestamp, multiply the value by 1000 (so that it has microseconds for JavaScript, and then pass the value to dojo date to format it). 
You shouldn't have any problems editing this to the format you need.

You provided examples that your dates are like "1", "2", "3", which is clearly wrong. Those aren't dates.. so this is the best you can do unless you edit your question.

```
 chart1.addAxis("x",{
            labelFunc: function(n){              
                if(isNaN(dojo.number.parse(n)) || dojo.number.parse(n) % 1 != 0){
                    return " ";
                }
                else {
                    // I am assuming that your timestamp needs to be multiplied by 1000. 
                    var date = new Date(dojo.number.parse(n) * 1000);
                    return dojo.date.locale.format(date,  {
                        selector: "date",
                        datePattern: "dd MMMM",
                        locale: "en"
                    });
                }
            },
            maxLabelSize: 100
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response. I already have the time values formatted as text (within the store) which I'd like to apply to the labels. I've used a sequence of numbers so that my points appear at regular intervals (as my times wont always be consecutive days). Using the raw milliseconds value would cause large gaps between values.